# How do I create a correct hasOne relation between two objects with loopback and angular

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, loopbackjs

I've recently started to code in angular as the frontend code and was planning to use loopback (www.loopback.io) as my backend (with a mongodb for my storage).
Now, as a basic idea I'm just creating a login form and register form and will go on from there. Yet, I can't seem to get my models correct, especially the relations between them.

I'd like a user model for the basic username/password stuff, and a person model where I can store more info like firstname, lastname, and more.
I'm currently using the "default" User model that you get out of the box and created a person model with the needed properties.
What I can't get correct though, is the link between the two (a one to one relation, so the HasOne relation).

These are my models:

**user.json**

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "person": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "Person",
      "foreignKey": "id"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

**person.json**

```
{
  "name": "Person",
  "plural": "Person",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "FirstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "LastName": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

**my register function**
*(I'm using the automaticaly generated lb-services file you can extract with the angular SDK provided by loopback, that's why you just see stuff like "User.create" in stead of a "real" api call)*

```
function register(email, password, firstname, lastname) {
      var usr = User.create({
          email: email,
          password: password
        }).$promise;

      var prs = usr.person.create({
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname
      });
      return usr;
    }
```

There's bound to be a bunch of stuff wrong here, I just don't know what. The user gets created in the database, yet I can't seem to instantly also create a "person" object and link that to the newly created user.

Any help is appreciated, cause I can't seem to find that many resources online that use angular and loopback with the generated lb-services file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you reference undefined property `person` of `usr` instance.

Create person using User resource, in success callback:

```
function register(email, password, firstname, lastname) {
      var usr = User.create({
          email: email,
          password: password
        }, function() {
          User.person.create({ userId: usr.id }, {
            firstname: firstname,
            lastname: lastname 
          }, function(person) {
            console.log('Persone created:', persone)
          })         
        });

      return usr;
    }
```

Comment: I've manage to find this exact solution yesterday while trying out different things, but, I'll accept your answer as the "correct" one, seeing I haven't answered my own question yesterday ;)